# There are $n$ horses. At a time only $k$ horses can run in a single race. What is the minimum number of races required to find the $m$ fastest horses?

Tags: co.combinatorics

The following question was asked and not (yet) answered at [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209790/how-to-find-a-total-order-with-constrained-comparisons).

> There are $n$ horses. At a time only $k$ horses can run in the single race. What is the minimum number of races required to find the top $m$ fastest horses? Please explain your answer.

The $n = 25, k = m = 5$ case was a Google interview question and there are various answers on the web. But I am not sure what the right answer should be for this. Any ideas?

Comment: Try math.stackexchange instead f MO.

Comment: @Misha: I have already posted the MSE link.

Comment: This seems like a nontrivial algorithms question to me. It may be a standard result for the right people, but I don't think it is obvious and I would be interested in learning the answer. Voting to reopen.

Comment: If $k=2$, this is a well studied but not solved problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_sorting . I have to assume that someone knows something about larger $k$.

Comment: @David: This is even weaker than partial sorting, since we don't need to know the exact rank of elements $1$ to $m$, just the set of elements in those positions.

Comment: Indeed, for k=2 you are looking at $m$ order statistics, which is linear in $n$.

Comment: It is clear that O(nlogn) is an upper bound on what is necessary, simply by using a race as a comparison (and forgetting about 3 of the horses) and doing something like mergesort to get a complete ranking.  For a complete ranking with races, information theory should yield the same
order as a lower bound.  For ranking a small fraction m of the n horses,
it may be possible to do it in O(nlogm), but I would expect the constants
for small m to outweigh logm, so practical methods would look like O(nm) in those cases.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.12.02

Comment: I just wanted to say that this is the same as [Generalization of a horse-racing puzzle](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/50737/generalization-of-a-horse-racing-puzzle?rq=1).

Comment: I believe the Google interview question was $m=3$ rather than $m=5$.

Comment: It isn't clearly stated whether we have to plan all the races in advance or we can plan each race after knowing the results of the previous races.  The answer could change.

Comment: Phrase "*Please explain your answer*" sounds... I don't know. Is it necessary?

Comment: This has been asked before, now I cannot find the other question but see http://www.researchgate.net/publication/3042594_Sorting_n_objects_with_a_k-sorter

Answer (score 15):

A trivial lower bound is $n/k$, since clearly every horse must race to obtain the answer.

I think we can get $O(n/k)$ upper bound, by adapting the median-of-medians selection algorithm.

First, note that, up to a constant factor, this problem is equivalent to finding the $m$th best horse. For the reduction one way, simply find the $m$ best horses and the $m-1$ best horses and see which horse mysteriously disappeared. For the reduction the other way, find the $m$th best horse, then race every other against it to find which are better and which are worse. (In fact, you don't need to do this - it's not hard to check that if you've found the $m$th best horse through repeated racing, you already know which are better and which are worse.)

For $k=2$, the [median-of-medians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) algorithm is known to give an $O(n)$ time bound, as was pointed out by Ralph Furmaniak. We will also use this to handle $k\leq 4$.

So assume $k\geq 5$ and is odd. Let $T(n)$ be the time it takes to find the $m$th horse among $n$ horses. Then divide the horses into groups of $k$, race them in time $n/k$, and take the median of each. Then select the median of those medians in time $T(n/k)$, and pivot on it in time $n/(k-1)$. (to pivot, the pivot horse must race each other horse only once. This allows us to remove at least $n(k+1)/4k$ of the horses, so we can find the $m$th horse in time $T(n (3k-1)/4k)$. So we get:

$$T(n) \leq T\left(\frac{n}{k}\right) + T\left(  \frac{n(3k-1)}{4k}\right) + \frac{n}{k}+\frac{n}{k-1} $$

By induction,

$$T(n) \leq \frac{4k}{k-3} \cdot \left( \frac{n}{k}+\frac{n}{k-1} \right) = O \left(\frac{n}{k}\right)$$

In fact we obtain an explicit constant of $8+o(1)$.

This ignores non-unique divisibility, which should only lead to a small error term unless $k$ is very large as a fraction of $n$.